# Meteorjs send variable from server to client

Tags: javascript, meteor

So I'm trying to send some data from server to client. Here is my client code that calls a method:

```
 'change #yes' : function (event){

        Meteor.call("readHeaders", Meteor.user().emails[0].address+'/'+Session.get("file1"), 
            function(err, result){
                console.log(result);
        }); 
    },
```

and here is the method that is being called:

```
readHeaders: function(fileName){

        Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
        var myFuture = new Future();
        var nodeFS = Meteor.npmRequire('node-fs');
        nodeFS.readFile("/Users/ray/Desktop/juju/upload/"+fileName,'utf8', function read(err, data){
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var headers = data.slice(0,data.indexOf('\n')).split(",");

            myFuture.return(headers);

        });
        myFuture.wait();
    }

});
var somefunction = function(fileName, cb){
    var nodeFS = Meteor.npmRequire('node-fs');
        nodeFS.readFile("/"+fileName,'utf8', function read(err, data){
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            var headers = data.slice(0,data.indexOf('\n')).split(",");

            console.log(headers);
            return headers;

        });
}
```

Here I'm using fibers, but I have also tried to use wrapAsync, to no avail. Does anyone know how to pass a variable from the server to the client in Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to a plain rest API if you so chose to.

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/file', function (req, res, next) {
  var filename = req.body.filename;
  res.write(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/' + filename));
  res.end();
});
```

Then on the client something like

```
HTTP.get('/file', { filename: 'file1.txt' }, function () {
  console.log('finished')
});
```

Comment: What I want to do is read a particular file and return a particular line back to the client to display. In your example, it seems like your trying to upload a file to a folder on the server.

Comment: it just reads the whole file and sends it back to the client. Your code already finds a single line so I made a minimal example to send a variable to the client easily